# error when try run ruby-mode in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

in the past when I type ruby-mode in emacs this work great but now appear in the buffer Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "cannot open load file" "cedet)

what is cedet?...where would it be?

when run Lisp slime this work perfectly...I know it error must be a newbie mistake but I don't know what can I do? and I'm newbie with emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Cedet is [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/).  I don't know why it stopped working, but if you install CEDET it might work.  The ruby-mode on my system (version 1.8 or 1.9.1) doesn't seem to use CEDET, so perhaps you're running a newer version, or a development version, or you have some hook installed to use CEDET for something.

On Debian, it's `apt-get install cedet-common`.  I don't know where it would be on your system.